# Rails 3.* Devise Facebook OmniAuth intermittently fails with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, facebook-authentication

I followed the steps that are described in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview and have a method in user model like this:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.extra.raw_info
  if user = self.find_by_email(data.email)
    user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    self.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
  end
end
```

I intermittently get errors like

A NoMethodError occurred in omniauth_callbacks#facebook:

undefined method `email' for "false":String
app/models/user.rb:138:in`find_for_facebook_oauth'

that I haven't been able to reproduce. What is the source of this problem?

Comment: There's probably a case where `raw_info` returns `"false"`. Why? I dont know... I thought that `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` was a simple hash, so I'm not sure how they can call `access_token.extra.raw_info`. Maybe they transform it into an openstruct or something like that.

Comment: exactly. the value corresponding to raw_info is supposed to be a hash containing values like email, etc. but this time, I just get "false". I couldn't figure out the cases when this happens.

Comment: Maybe when the user refuses to give permissions?

Comment: I thought so too and tried that scenario, but I couldn't reproduce the problem. it fails gracefully and redirects to the right page with the relevant error message.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what causes this either. Here's a work-around that simply creates a new object:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data = access_token.extra.raw_info
  if data == "false"
    self.new
  elsif user = self.find_by_email(data.email)
    user
  else # Create a user with a stub password. 
    self.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
  end
end
```

The controller code shown in the example will then work - it will redirect the user to sign up.